# Dual monitors does not work properly

Tags: multiple-monitors, 22.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot with Windows and the dual monitors simple does not work on Ubuntu. I thought it could possibly be a bad DP connection, but in Windows it works well. In Ubuntu I can access both monitors if I use one display or screen mirroring. Somebody can help me?

Comment: You have tagged 22.04 but the question body says Ubuntu Core 22. That is the only version of Ubuntu that uses a single digit version number. Please edit the question.

Comment: Just edited! Thanks for the help